# Java pass class variable inside Diamond operator

Tags: java, java-8

I have a doubt in a Java project:

```
public class example {

   public Data getData() {
        List<Users> users = usersService.findByClinicId(id);
        Type targetListType = new TypeToken<List<UserDTO>>() {}.getType();
        List<UserDTO> usersDTO = modelMapper.map(users, targetListType);

        List<Personas> profesionales = personasService.findProfesionalsByClinicId(id);
        targetListType = new TypeToken<List<PersonaDTO>>() {}.getType();
        List<PersonaDTO> profesionalesDTO = modelMapper.map(profesionales, targetListType);

        List<Personas> auxiliares = personasService.findAuxiliarsByClinicId(id);
        targetListType = new TypeToken<List<PersonaDTO>>() {}.getType();
        List<PersonaDTO> auxiliaresDTO = modelMapper.map(auxiliares, targetListType);

        List<Prescripciones> prescripciones = prescripcionesService.findProfesionalsByClinicId(id);
        targetListType = new TypeToken<List<PrescriptionNameDTO>>() {}.getType();
        List<PrescriptionNameDTO> prescripcionesDTO = modelMapper.map(prescripciones, targetListType);

       profesionales = entityToDTO(PersonaDTO.class, profesionales);

    ...
   }

    private <T> List<T> entityToDTO(Class<T> clazz, List<T> list) {
        Type targetListType = new TypeToken<List<clazz>>() {}.getType();
        List<PersonaDTO> auxiliaresDTO = modelMapper.map(list, targetListType);

    }
}
```

The idea is to reduce the code of the `getData` function using the `entityToDTO` function.

The problem I have is:

- In the method `entityToDTO`, I want to pass in TypeToken first parameter the type of List that I want, but it doesn't accept List, where clazz is the variable that has the Class name.

Is there a way to pass inside the List diamond operator a variable with the type of class I want to use?

UPDATE:
The idea is to reduce the number of lines of `getData` function.

Comment: `entityToDTO<PersonaDTO>(profesionales)`?

Comment: I use a library that is passing Entities to DTO, so it need to know the class of the DTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update your entityToDTO method as follow :

```
public static <D, T> List<D> entityToDTO(final Collection<T> sourceList, Class<D> destinationCLass) {
        if (Objects.isNull(sourceList)) {
            return null;
        }
        return sourceList.stream().map(entity -> modelMapper.map(entity, destinationCLass))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

   }
```

Comment: You haven't use `destinationCLass` argument inside `TypeToken<List<...>>`

Comment: You're right it is not possible to use the destinationClass. I have updated my response with an implementation that suit your need.

Comment: I don't know if this is the same that I was doing inside the `getData` function: In my code I mapped a List. In your solution you make a map of the streamed List and perform the mapping of entities for every element. I don't know If my code (passing List) internally do the same thing.

Comment: In my code I do the same as your getData, I mapped a list (of source object ) to a list od distination object, in your example the method will be called as : List<PersonaDTO> auxiliaresDTO = entityToDTO(auxiliares, PersonaDTO.class);

Answer (score 6):

Why not pass the `Type` instead?

```
private <T> List<T> entityToDTO(Type type, List<T> list) {
     return modelMapper.map(list, type);
}
```

And on the caller side, for example:

```
Type typeToUse = TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, UserDTO.class).getType();
```

Comment: I would like to get the two lines inside the entityToDTO function. It will not help me to do a function with one line.

Comment: For me it's useless to create a function entityToDTO with one line of code inside. The idea was to make getData function smaller in lines size

Comment: @albert some people tent to think quite the opposite; but this is un-related to your problem to begin with.

Comment: @albert *In the method entityToDTO, I want to pass in TypeToken first parameter the type of List that I want, but it doesn't accept List, where clazz is the variable that has the Class name* - where have you seen the part about making it smaller in size?

Comment: Functions are to re-use code, make code smaller and more readable. And if I have to change one thing of the code, is better to change in one generic function that in all parts with the same functionality

Comment: @albert Adopting best practices for the language you’re working in (like this suggested solution) will also improve your code’s readability.

Comment: I think this will not work, because the generic type of the input `list` is the same as the output

Comment: @Lino this was just some pseudo-code, really, since I have no idea what `modelMapper` is

Comment: @Eugene probably only something like this would work: `private <T> List<T> entityToDTO(Class<T> type, List<?> list) {` else one would probably get unchecked cast exceptions and so on. But you're right, as long as we don't know what `modelmapper` is we can only guess

Answer (score 0):

I think, to reduce `getData()` you should add filtering.

1. Create search request object with set of variable for filtering
2. Put it to the database
3. Build SQL: SearchRequest -> SQL
4. Retrieve only that data from DB, that you want.

This is general approach:

```
class SearchDataRequest {
   private String id;
   private Type type;
   //... other parameters 
}

public Data getData(SearchDataRequest request) {
    return reposiotry.getDataByFilter(request);
}
```

DAO Layer:

```
public Data getDataByFilter(SearchDataRequest request) {
    String sql = buildSqlForRequest(request);
    return executeSql(sql);
}
```